# How to transform this sql into jpql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this situation:

```
@Query(value="select distinct mensal, anual, porcentagem from resultados where id_empresa = :id_empresa and tipo_tarifa= :tipo_tarifa", nativeQuery=true)
List<Resultados> listarResultadosPorTarifa(@Param("id_empresa") Integer id_empresa, @Param("tipo_tarifa") String tipo_tarifa);
```

When I run my application I got this error:

> id column is not in resultset

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try adding the id column to the resultset?

Comment: when I add it I cannot get the result I need.

Comment: can you share Resultados class?

Answer (score 0):

### **The issue you are getting:-**

When I run my application I got this error:

```
id column is not in resultset
```

### **Reason:-**

The reason is you are trying to fetch [mensal, anual, porcentagem] these three fields and trying to store in an Entity which is wrong approach. You can try the following example,

## **Solution A:**

As of Now please consider below class as your Entity:

ResultAdos.java

```
@Entity
class ResultAdos{
    Integer empresaId;
    String mensal;
    String anual;
    String porcentAgem;
    String tipoTarifa;

    //getter
    //setter

}
```

ResultRepository.java

```
@Query(value="select * from resultados where id_empresa = :id_empresa and tipo_tarifa= :tipo_tarifa", nativeQuery=true)
List<Resultados> listarResultadosPorTarifa(@Param("id_empresa") Integer id_empresa, @Param("tipo_tarifa") String tipo_tarifa);
```

- Above query will work perfectly
- If you don't want to change your query then you can use the following example,

## **Solution B:-**

- Create another normal class with suitable name ResultDto:

ResultDto.java

```
class ResultDto{
    String mensal;
    String anual;
    String porcentAgem;

    //getter
    //setter

}
```

ResultRepository.java

```
@Query(value="select distinct mensal, anual, porcentagem from resultados where id_empresa = :id_empresa AND tipo_tarifa= :tipo_tarifa", nativeQuery=true)
List<ResultDto> listarResultadosPorTarifa(@Param("id_empresa") Integer id_empresa, @Param("tipo_tarifa") String tipo_tarifa);
```

-- In JPQL the name of fields/columnName should be from your entity and the name of table should be same as the name of Entity like this 'ResultAdos'.